# Import a module, from inside another module

Tags: python, module

Basically I have written two modules for my Python Program. I need one module to import the other module.

Here is a sample of my file structure.

```
test_app 
    main.py
    module_1
        __init__.py
        main.py

    module_2
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

`Main.py` is able to import either of the two modules, but I need `module_1` to import `module_2`, is that possible?

Comment: Any reason for not having an !__init__.py directly under test_app too?

Comment: Help with package imports. subpackages work better.. see my answer.

Comment: In Python terminology, `module_1` and `module_2` are packages, not modules. `main`, `module_1.main`, and `module_2.main` are your modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is set to `test_app`, you should be able to import `module1` from `module2` and vice versa.

I assume that you run your program like this:

```
python test_app/main.py
```

and that the program imports `module1.main`, which in turn imports `module2.main`. In that case there is no need to alter the value of `PYTHONPATH`, since Python has already added the test_app directory to it. See the [Module Search Path](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) section in the Python docs.

Comment: No need to set the `PYTHONPATH`: "the `import` statement first looks in the containing package before looking in the standard module search path" ([Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)).

Comment: But in this case there is no containing package, since test_app does not contain a `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 3):

If you started your program from `test_app/main.py`, you can just use `from module_1 import main` in `test_app/module_2/main.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you add an (empty) `__init__.py` to test_app, test_app will be a package. This means that python will search for modules/packages a bit smarter.

Having done that, in module1, you can now write  `import test_app.module2` (or `import .. module2`) and it works.

(This answer was combined from other comments and answers here, hence CW)

Answer (score 1):

This question ask been answered by the official python documents, in the section called ***Intra-package References***. [python modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html)

The submodules often need to refer to each other.
You don't need to care about the PYTHONPATH, declaration of the relative path will do.
For your case,

just type "import .. module2" in the module_1/main.py

Answer (score 0):

sure does.

In your module_1 module. In any file:

```
from module_2 import your_function, your_class
```